# Should you quit work as a programmer if you’re slow?

Tags: resignation, career-switch

Ever since I started working as a programmer I have found it pretty difficult. The issue is simply that I can not work at the speed that is expected of me. Everyone else seems to get their code completed much faster. I end up having to work evenings and weekends, and even then, I am still almost always behind on my deadlines. I am starting to think maybe I’m not cut out for programming, and I should quit. I started my most recent job about three years ago, and I was hoping I would get better over time, but it seems like I am still not up to speed. I really wish managers would just let me complete work in my own time.

In my defence, I do feel that I haven’t had much opportunity to develop my skills. I have only actually worked on a few projects from start to finished. Mostly I have been asked to do cases and modifications. I had another job previously, but I was mainly doing bug fixing and testing, and before that I did a one year masters course in computer science, without any previous background in computer science. The course itself only involved coding on maybe a quarter of the modules.

Maybe I should find a new line of work, but I am now in my early thirties and I am getting really tired of spending so much time and energy trying to carve out a career for myself. I’d like to find some to marry and maybe start a family, which is not very likely to happen if I’m spending all my time working.
Any advice or thoughts?

Comment: Programming != CS. When you work overtime, is that because of others' expectations or your own?

Comment: Of course.  Remember what Homer Simpson always says: “If something's hard to do, then it's not worth doing.”

Comment: Is there a career path that interests you more?

Comment: @Leonard, Before joining this company, did you have some good programming experiences either at your undergraduate college or in other intern jobs ? If you didn't have any sufficient programming experience before working for this company, then it is reasonable to expect that you will need sometime to get up to the speed that other programmers are working at.

Comment: How did you get a masters in computer science in just one year with no background in the science? Are we talking about a Masters degree from the University of Timbuktoo or something?

Comment: If you are experienced at finding bugs and thus your code doesn't have many, I would consider you to be working very well. Don't sweat what others are doing as if they are meeting schedule, they are likely to be leaving a number of bugs in their code.

Comment: I am curious how you got in this situation:. "I did a one year masters course in computer science, without any previous background in computer science. The course itself only involved coding on maybe a quarter of the modules." -- so by my estimation, it sounds like you've taken approximately *one single course* that involved programming (and not even focused on that). Did you think that prepared you for an industry coding job? Did someone tell you it would? Did you passionately enjoy coding when you discovered it?

Answer (score 10):

There is a MASSIVE difference in the potential productive output between someone who is 4-7 years experienced on a platform and proficient in the task they're working on, and someone else with less experience or who's still being on boarded.

This is normal and it's no reason to quit. You will be slower, for a while.

This doesn't matter. All you need to do is get good at communicating expectations on when you can complete the work, and if asked, explain why / that you still are getting ramped up on the project.

Don't quit, don't think you're just not cut out for it.

Just focus on trying to learn what it is that is keeping you from the level these other guys are at. It's likely it's just experience and the memory and knowledge of where all of the important checkboxes are at.

And regardless of how fast the other guys may be... They are at 100% capacity. They're not going to *replace* you - you were hired because **As fast as they are, they alone are not enough**.

The business needs someone else to get the additional work done, and that is you.

Additionally... Don't work weekends. Especially if you're not getting paid for it. Communicate if you're not able to make a deadline.

If you don't make management and your project managers aware that you're not able to make a deadline, you are giving them the impression that it's do-able for you in a 40 hour week and you are convincing them that you may just be able to take on even more. You need to nip this in the bud and not be afraid to fail a task with an unreasonable deadline.

It may be that they're intentionally giving you high pressure deadlines to gaslight you and get you to guilt yourself into working extra for free. Who knows.

But again, do your best within the standard work hours, communicate politely if you are at capacity and believe the task will be finished Wednesday even though they're asking for Monday, and good quality managers will be very happy with you. If they're not, it's a serious red flag and it's indicative of manipulative management that's just going to mentally abuse you into thinking you're worthless so you sit there 8 years putting in 50-60 hour weeks, getting told you're not doing enough and that's why they're cheating you out of Promised bonuses and promotions and raises

And even if you *are* under performing to expectations... What do you think they're going to do? Fire you, let the position sit open 2-4 months while they search for a replacement, pay a recruiter a 20k commission for them and then start over on boarding that person?  Don't stress about anything. Follow the rules, try to do a good job, and don't let it get in your head. Your managers will tell you if they need something from you, consider if it's possible without ruining your work life balance and go from there.

You will get better over time and the experience will be extremely valuable to you AND the organization. Build out knowledge documentation as you learn the things too

Comment: This is good comment. Additionally, what exactly is difficult when programming. From past experience, modifying someone else's code is far more difficult then modifying my own code. New IDE's can be a pain to get up to speed with. New platform can be a pain to get up to speed with. So, if you wanted to make a program your way on your own equipment using your tools of choice, is this still difficult for you?

Answer (score 2):

There are people who work slowly, and their code works. There are others who are a lot faster, and then when QA tests their code it fails, a bug report is produced, someone wastes their time by finding and fixing the bug, then more problems are found, and in the end twice as much time is spent because of the "fast" software developer.

Guess who I prefer to work with me?

Answer (score 0):

### Show your boss you're struggling

A lot of people assume your boss is just there to get work out of you. Some are but a good one knows each employee is an investment and will do their best to help you improve.

Start by dropping the over-time for a few reasons.

- Often when people work long hours they actually end up being less productive per hour - this will only exacerbate your belief that your slow.
- Use your time to work on you. Do some extra reading and learning around react any other languages you use - if you want this to be your career this is an investment for your future.
- You aren't paid for the overtime, as a rule try not to work it :)

You should then talk to your boss about work loads and how much extra you've been doing. They may have schemes they've used in the past (mentoring, training etc).

Comment: Often working long hours makes you not just less productive _per hour_, it makes you less productive _per week_. One rule of thumb is one person working 40hrs for six weeks and another working 60hrs for six weeks produce the same output - after that the 60hrs person is so exhausted they will produce less.

Comment: When working to exhaustion, can't learn anything. To learn how to be a better programmer, we have to have time away from the job.

Comment: Going into very long hours, not only are they less productive, one starts to generate lots of errors -- so actually *negative* productivity.

Comment: @gnasher completely agree with all the comments saying over working isn't productive. Not sure if I have a typo here but that is exactly what I'm saying too.

Comment: Lio, you wrote "less productive ***per hour***". If you work 60 hours and were 10% less productive per hour, you would still achieve more than I would working 40 hours. But you soon reach the stage where your total productivity in 60 hours is less than mine in 40 hours. (Plus what Daniel said correctly, that anyone's work is rubbish once they are tired).

Comment: @gnasher729 Ah, I see why you might think there is a disagreement but I'm not making a statement about general productivity. Instead I'm just trying to address the OP's belief that they're slow. I'm just saying "if you overwork yourself you _will_ be slower"